# How I pass string inside R function

Tags: r, string, function, dataframe

I have a df and I would like to do a function with the names of header and return linear models.

I'm trying this:

```
a <- function(j,k){
  reg1 <- lm(data$j ~ data$k)
  summary(reg1)
}

a(j="hour",k="score")
```

It's NULL for 'data$j'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `$` when passing column name as variable. Here are couple of ways in which you can do this.

1. Use reformulate to create a formula object

```
a <- function(data, j,k){
  reg1 <- lm(reformulate(k, j), data = data)
  summary(reg1)
}
```

2. `lm` also accepts formula as string so you don't necessarily need to convert it into formula object.

```
a <- function(data, j,k){
  reg1 <- lm(sprintf('%s~%s', j, k), data = data)
  summary(reg1)
}
```

You can call this as :

```
a(mtcars, 'mpg', 'cyl')

#Call:
#lm(formula = sprintf("%s~%s", j, k), data = data)

#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
#cyl          -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
#F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10
```

Note that I added `data` as an additional argument in the function. It is generally a better practice to pass data object in the function rather than relying it to be evaluated in global environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If you are going tu use strings which are as variables in a dataframe, it is better to invoke them in a function using `[[]]`. Here the code of your function with slight changes:

```
a <- function(j,k){
  reg1 <- lm(data[[j]] ~ data[[k]])
  summary(reg1)
}

a(j="hour",k="score")
```

And a small example using `iris` dataset:

```
#Example
data=iris
#Code
a(j="Sepal.Length",k="Petal.Length")
```

You can further tune your function `a` if needed.